# C++ List of Base Classes and How to Determine Class Type

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have a base class `line` which has a child class `arc` (note that additional classes will inherit from `line`)... I need to store a list, or `vector` of `line` objects that may be a `line` or an `arc`. `arc` has an additional property that `line` does not. So as I'm working with my lists, or `vector` of `line` objects, how do I determine whether the object is a `line` or an `arc`?

I have prepared a small sample program and put in comments with pseudo-code a sample of what I would be trying to accomplish. Is this even possible?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

struct point
{
    double x;
    double y;
};

class line
{
    public:

        point start;
        point end;

};

class arc: public line
{
    public:

        point center;

};


int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{


    vector<line*> a;
    a.push_back( new line );
    a.push_back( new arc );

    for( vector<line*>::iterator i = a.begin(); i < a.end(); i++ )
    {
        (*i)->start.x = 10;
        (*i)->start.y = 11;
        (*i)->end.x = 101;
        (*i)->end.y = 102;
        //if( type of (*i) is arc ) 
        //{
        //  (i)->center.x = 111;
        //  (i)->center.y = 112;
        // }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop, try this:

```
arc *ar = dynamic_cast<arc *>(*i);
if ( NULL != ar ) {
 // it's an arc!
}else {
  // it's just a line
}
```

Sid is also right...use virtual functions for this instead.  Using dynamic_cast for simple cases such as this is generally considered poor style.

Comment: `arc` will have various functions such as `getRadius()` that will not apply to `line`, so it makes no sense to me to use virtual functions on this project. I've seen similar examples to the one you posted here, but I get this compiler error when I try that... `cannot dynamic_cast ‘i.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator* [with _Iterator = line**, _Container = std::vector<line*>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::reference = line*&]()’ (of type ‘class line*’) to type ‘class arc*’ (source type is not polymorphic)`

Comment: Ah yes, the missing vtable.  Well...you could add one by making the (empty) destructor virtual in class line.  Not the best approach but it will work.

Comment: So, back to Sid's point, why do you need to keep them in a container holding line*?  If you don't have any virtual functions here, it hardly seems appropriate.

Comment: I got your example to work by adding at least one virtual function to the base class. You say this is a bad practice, but unless I want to bloat my base class with virtual members it REALLY does not need, then I don't see any other options beside this one...

Comment: Because I need a list of of these types of objects and each individual item could be a `line` or an `arc` or some other type of `line` that I haven't added yet. Also, they will be written/read to/from a plain text file, so I will need to determine as I iterate through them what type they really are so it can be indicated in the file.

Comment: To write them to a plain text file you can have a virtual method getName() that returns the fully qualified name of each class. If you are serializing these I would prefer this to RTTI and have more control over the class name I want to serialize something as.

Answer (score 1):

```
class curve
{
public:
    typedef void * type;

public:
    virtual type rtti() const = 0;
};

#define     
DEFINE_RTTI  \
    public: \
        virtual type rtti() const { return desc(); }        \
    public: \
        inline static type desc() { return &desc; } \

class line : public curve
{
    DEFINE_RTTI;
};

class arc : public curve
{
    DEFINE_RTTI;
};

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Main program
int main()
{
    arc arc_;
    line line_;

    curve *curve_ = new arc();

    _ASSERT(arc_.rtti() == arc::desc());
    _ASSERT(arc_.rtti() != line::desc());

    _ASSERT(line_.rtti() != arc::desc());
    _ASSERT(line_.rtti() == line::desc());

    return 0;
}
```

This rtti works inside one module (exe or dll), if you want use it in several modules you have to build class dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to determine? If you absolutely need to you can use the typeid field via RTTI. But normally if you use virtual methods, if your program is well designed you shouldn't need to know what a class is. Calling a virtual function on a base class reference or pointer will call the appropriate instance's method based on what it is pointing to. 
That's the whole point of having polymorphism via class hierarchies.

But again, use typeid if you absolutely need to know what class an instance belongs to.

Also, you can't access derived class member data via base class pointers. you can only talk via the base class interface. that's the whole point of abstraction.
One ugly way around is to create a fat interface that is give accessors/mutators to these data members in your base class interface as virtual member functions.

Comment: Aside from the `main` function, there is absolutely no functions in my example, let alone virtual ones. I have tried using the `typeid()` function to determine the class type, however, all of my efforts have resulted in compiler errors, or it returned the pointer type and not what the actual class is. And finally, that doesn't solve the problem of being able to access the members of the object that are not defined in the base class...

Comment: Are you sure you have rtti enabled in your compiler. I think a lot of them have to be given the option --rtti-enabled or something like that. See my edit.

Comment: Yes, rtii is enabled by default in g++ which I'm using at the moment. You have introduced some new terms (accessors, mutators) to me that I'm not familiar with. Do you have any examples of doing it like this?